# Fill values from static table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a static table in my Postgre that is like

[image]

now imagine I have another table where there is a cycle entity with unique id, and has a lot of consecutive states like

```
cycle   state        created_at
1       lead         1/1/2000
1       contacted    1/2/2000
1       won          1/3/2000
2       lead         1/1/2000
2       opportunity  2/1/2000
```

Some values are missing in between and I want to fill them with values of the states that its order is in-between.

How can I achieve that with pure SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Cross join the states with the distinct cycles and then left join the cycles.

```
SELECT x."cycle",
       s."state",
       a."created_at"
       FROM "static" s
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                               "cycle"
                               FROM "another") x
            LEFT JOIN "another" a
                      ON a."state" = s."state"
                         AND a."cycle" = x."cycle"
       ORDER BY x."cycle",
                s."order";
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=782da05a6600aa28e4b2531eee7f4e17)

Answer (score -1):

I would leave gaps in between the order values and then deal with it in the application layer programmatically.